# Why Do We Say An HTML5

Tags: html

Totally random but why do we say "an HTML5"? I've seen it in a couple of articles and books and have been a bit thrown off by it, as I would think to write "a HTML5 book" rather than "an HTML5 book".

Here's an example: http://www.w3.org/html/logo/

Comment: Try this on http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's pronounced "aych te em el"(or similair), the first sound is vocal, and thus "an", not an "a".
Not sure this is truly programming related though ).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because for <strike>acronyms</strike> *initialisms* you pronounce every letter, and the word for the letter 'H' sounds like 'aitch', and hence audibly begins with a vowel. *"An Aitch Tee Em Ell Five Book."*

See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms

Comment: Got ya. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

H is pronounced /ˈeɪtʃ/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IPA_for_English#Key

> An is the older form (related to one,
>   cognate to German ein; etc.), now **used
>   before words starting with a vowel
>   sound**, regardless of whether the word
>   begins with a vowel letter.[8]
>   Examples: a light-water reactor; a
>   sanitary sewer overflow; an SSO; a
>   HEPA filter (because HEPA is
>   pronounced as a word rather than as
>   letters); an hour; a ewe; a one-armed
>   bandit; an heir; a unicorn (begins
>   with 'yu', a consonant sound).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles